# What is the correct way to install openconnect(ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7) package on CentOs 7

Tags: centos, openconnect

Take a look at [all openconnect versions](ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/) & [this](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1229989).

What is the correct way to install openconnect(ocserv-0.12.3) package on CentOs 7?

I tried these commands :

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum repolist enabled
sudo yum info ocserv
```

But it shows me version 0.12.2, not version 0.12.3!
Now how can i install version 0.12.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As version 0.12.3 is EPEL candidate you can install it via downloading the package (RPM) and install it. Or compile it from source. But I will recommend you to install available in EPEL package and do not hurry up. The command you can use is:

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/ocserv/0.12.3/1.el7/x86_64/ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

OF course you can install it directly via `rpm` but this will bring warning messages later when you use again `yum`

```
rpm -i wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/ocserv/0.12.3/1.el7/x86_64/ocserv-0.12.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, teach me how did you find that rpm?

Comment: @SilverLight, check you second link. And you will see RPM's there (for different platforms) And for each there is download link

Comment: Thanks man / I installed it like a charm...

Comment: @SilverLight, in such case feel free to accept my answer :)